# installing external softwares in bootable Ubuntu in USB

Tags: installation, usb, live-usb

I am new to Ubuntu, and this question I am asking here is more about a curiosity. I already have Ubuntu installed on a pendrive, but while roaming the internet, I came across this link [Ubuntu Installation in USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator). I want to know that if, in a LiveUSB Ubuntu, we install any other external softwares (for example, AVG Antivirus), can this pendrive (with the external softwares installed) be used on another computer and still be able to use this external software?

**EDITED**

I have installed kubuntu using [universal usb installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and created a live kubuntu in my pendrive. While booting kubuntu it asked for two options 1)*Try Kubuntu* or 2)*Install Kubuntu*. I have clicked *Try Kubuntu* option and it went to the live kubuntu (not installed) desktop. Then i tried to install vlc using the [given tutorial](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) and it too were succesful. After installation of VLC I opened It and run some videos also.

But when i restarted the computer and used "*Try Kubuntu*"  option, for my surprice i was unable to find the installed VLC player in the kubuntu. Can any one tell me what is the problem how i can rectify this.

Comment: IMPORTANT: Found solution for the above problem. Change the persistent range from 0 to 1/4GB (according to your need)then install kubuntu in USB  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install additional software in a pendrive created with that method and yes it can run in multiple computers but sometimes you can find hardware incompatibilities that will prevent you from running it.

I use quite often a USB hard disk with Ubuntu installed to repair Windows computers and it boots most of the time. If I should give a number, based on my faulty memory and personal experience, it could run 9 out of 10 times.